# List filename not contain some keywords in the dictory file

Tags: grep, ls

In a folder, there are lots of files, which contain timestamp information in the filename, for example,

```
callMic-13501358220-414404433.caf   (414404433 is the timestamp)
callMic-18901111584-414235643.caf
....
```

I also have a text file (timestamp.txt) which woule be used as a dictory. The text file contain lots of timestamp per line, as shown below.

```
414247851
414235643
414226229
....
..
```

i want to list all filenames which not contain the timestamp listed in  timestamp.txt.

Comment: *Dictory* is not an English word - do you mean **directory** (as in "folder" on disk), or did you mean a **dictionary** (as a data structure in memory) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -vFwf timstamp.txt filename.txt
```

if your filenames are not in file, you could

```
ls -1 or find magic..|grep -vFwf timestamp.txt
```

Comment: I think this is the way, although `filename.txt` should be populated with the list of the files.

Comment: thanks, I want to list filename NOT contain the keywords listed in timestamp.txt.

Comment: @seanlv did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes, I did. :)  but it didn't work. I used ls -1 |grep -vFwf timestamp.txt